# conda install psycopg2 errors

Tags: python, installation, anaconda, psycopg2

New mackbookpro running Catalina. Installed anaconda using homebrew. Tried to install psycopg2 using the command `conda install -c anaconda psycopg2` but failed due to package conflicts. Here's some of the output from the attempted install:

```
$ conda install -c anaconda psycopg2
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: / 
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort.
failed                                                                                                                                                \ 

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:

Output in format: Requested package -> Available versions

Package six conflicts for:
pyopenssl -> cryptography[version='>=2.8'] -> six[version='>=1.4.1']
pytest-doctestplus -> pytest[version='>=3.0'] -> six[version='>=1.10.0']
python-dateutil -> six[version='>=1.5']
nltk -> six
```

Any thoughts on what's happening or how to fix?

Comment: `conda update conda`, and then try it

Comment: Thanks. tried this and ran the install command again. No dice :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason might be there are too many conflicts between [anaconda==2020.02] and [70+ PACKAGES]
Try the following worked for me:

**conda -V**
**conda update -n base conda**

To ensure you are in version
conda 4.8.2
Then

`conda update --all`

Then the following packages will be DOWNGRADED:

anaconda                       2020.02-py37_0 --> custom-py37_1

Then

`conda install psycopg2`

Then packages libpq,psycopg2 would be installed, some packages would be updated, some packages would be superseded by higher-priority channel.

Comment: the Correct command is `conda update --all`

Comment: simply doing conda update --all seems to solve my problem. Just a note!

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same situation today and couldn't install psycopg2 using conda package manager. But when I tried to do the same with pip in Anaconda Prompt the installation went perfect and took less than a minute:

```
pip install psycopg2
```